# Assign a new value to a struct field

Tags: go, methods, struct

I have a problem with structure fields.

I've created a class `Point` with one method `Move()` that increases or decreases object variable `x` by `dx`. Another method `Print` is used to output results.

In `main()` a new instance is created with default `x = 3` and `dx = 2`, then I call `Move()` and `Print()`. I expect that value of `x` is changed during `Move()` and `Print()` will produce `Final x=5`, but instead of it displays this:

```
2014/07/28 15:49:44 New X=5
2014/07/28 15:49:44 Final X=3
```

What's wrong with my code?

```golang
type Point struct {
  x, dx int
}

func (s Point) Move() {
  s.x += s.dx
  log.Printf("New X=%d", s.x)
}

func (s Point) Print() {
  log.Printf("Final X=%d", s.x)
}

func main() {
  st := Point{ 3, 2 };
  st.Move()
  st.Print()
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a pointer receiver here or you are only changing a copy of the original object every time. Everything is [passed by value](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value) in go.

```
type Point struct {
  x, dx int
}

func (s *Point) Move() {
  s.x += s.dx
  log.Printf("New X=%d", s.x)
}

func (s *Point) Print() {
  log.Printf("Final X=%d", s.x)
}

func main() {
  st := Point{ 3, 2 };
  st.Move()
  st.Print()
}
```

Comment: That's it! I used to ABAP too much, references to variables are passed by default into functions there. Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 1):

That's the difference between pointer receiver and value receiver

http://golang.org/doc/faq#methods_on_values_or_pointers