# Why is value changing after function execution?

Tags: go

I'm currently teaching myself Go, and I'm having trouble understanding a certain behavior:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type List struct {
    n int
}

func (l List) Increment() {
    l.n += 1
    l.LogState() // size: 1
}

func (l List) LogState() {
    fmt.Printf("size: %v\n", l.n)
}

func main() {
    list := List{}
    list.Increment()

    fmt.Println("----")
    list.LogState() // size: 0
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/-O24DiNPkxx

`LogState` is executed twice. The initial time, during the `Increment` call, it prints `size: 1` but after `Increment` has returned it prints `size: 0`. Why are those values different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28497254/struct-field-not-updated-when-implementing-interface-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994721/assign-a-new-value-to-golang-structure-field and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your nodes are not added to the original linkedList because you are not using pointer to the struct. So even if the `Increment` function in your example code changes the value. The copy of the struct is changed not the actual struct.

> You can declare methods with pointer receivers. This means the
>   receiver type has the literal syntax *T for some type T. (Also, T
>   cannot itself be a pointer such as *int.)

If you want to change the linkedlistNode struct counter to show the nodes added to the list you should be using a pointer type receiver on both methdos working to modify the linked list as:

```
func (l *LinkedList) AddInitialValue(v interface{})
func (l *LinkedList) LogState()
```

And Inside the main pass an address to the linkedList to use those pointer type receivers as:

```
func main() {
    list :=  &LinkedList{}
    list.AddInitialValue(9)

    fmt.Println("----")
    list.LogState() // size: 0
}
```

Working Code [Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JK8G95KpDXH)

**Note:-**

There are two reasons to use a pointer receiver.

> - To modify the value that its receiver points to.
> - To avoid copying the value on each method call. This can be more efficient if the receiver is a large struct

For more information go through [Method Sets](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets)

Answer (score 1):

With `Increment` and `LogState` defined the way you've defined them, you are working only with the **copy** of the value of `List`. This means that if you make some changes inside `Increment` function, they are visible only inside `Increment`'s function scope and only for the remainder of that particular scope's existence. To confirm you are always working with a copy of of the initial `List` value, you can log `&list` before executing `Increment` function and `&l` inside the same function.

If you want to make changes permanent, you should work with a pointer to a memory address. That means your your function should be defined like this:

```
func (l *List) Increment()

func (l *List) LogState()
```

This way, you are passing a memory reference (pointer to an address in memory) and every time you change a value of `l`, you are changing it on the passed memory reference and it reflects everywhere.